# Any good reference for digital architecture implementations of floating point arithmetic operations?

Tags: fpga, books, vhdl, floating-point

I am doing a thesis project. I need to make a FPGA implementation of a neural network. I want to implement some mathematical functions such as an exponential function.

Does anyone know of any good books about FPGAs, VHDL or digital architecture implementation of floating point arithmetic operations?

Comment: What's your skill level?  Do you need an intro to FPGAs and VHDL, or a reference for implementing floating-point operations with some recipes in VHDL?

Comment: @reemrevnivek: I´ve studied VHDL before, but I haven´t had a formal intro to FPGAs.Do you know any reference I should read about FPGAs? I have the feeling FPGAs is a wide world in the sense, every FPGA manufacturer has a different technology. Of course theres is something in common between all manufacturers...

Comment: Do you have a project or class page link? This sounds very interesting.

Comment: this has been converted to community wiki by your request.

Answer (score 8):

There are ANN techniques that don't require floating-point. You will find things much easier if you adopt one of those.

[Jim Austin's work](http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/arch/neural-networks/technologies) at York University comes to mind. He uses FPGAs and fixed-point DSPs.

EDIT: (Leon, I hope you don't mind me adding this list here)

- ["fpga neural networks"](http://www.fpga4fun.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=6820) discussion forum, in particular a FPGA NN where "The neuron uses 8bit numbers".
- ["FPGA Implementations of Neural Networks - a Survey of a Decade of Progress"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.1999&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Zhu and Sutton: lists many implementation techniques, and briefly mentions that floating point implementation technique has not yet been successful.
- ["FPGA neural net"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=FPGA%20neural%20net&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) search on Google Scholar

Comment: It´s difficult to me imagine something out of ecuations or whatever mathematical expressions. Well, at the end you have mathematical expressions and how do you implement it? That´s the questions.I suposse neural networks are interesting because they can be implemented on electronics (I don´t know imagine any signal processing application that it not based on mathematical expressions). Anyway, I have to use a Fuzzy Neural Networks and as I am concerned, Fuzzy Neural Networks are described by mathematical expressions.

Comment: Besides, I use the 'if then rule' form proposed by Takagi and Sugeno. This form is described by mathematical expressions.

Comment: Please, can you show me any reference about ANN techniques that don't require floating-point?

Comment: The link you have put it isn´t usefull, that web page don´t contain any link to documentation or libraries. May be I can access if I were a member of York University but I am not.

Comment: @Peterstone: it contains links to all the publications by that research group. That is the normal way for scientists to share their knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Professor Miriam Leeser's research group at the Reconfigurable Computing Laboratory at Northeastern University has developed an open source floating point library for Xilinx FPGAs in VHDL:
http://www.ece.neu.edu/groups/rcl/projects/floatingpoint/index.html

Answer (score 4):

They are starting on a package at [VHDL.org](http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/old_index.html).  [OptNgn](http://optngn.com/place/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=2&Itemid=53&TreeId=2) also have a library that is free (GPLv3).

Comment: Both links are dead now.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid IEEE floating point format, go with the format the TI DSP uses.  Ti has some good doc that goes along with one of the older DSPs that holds your hand through the operations.  From there you can start on your logic.

Comment: Please, could you put any link?

Comment: http://www.ise.pw.edu.pl/dydaktyka/psap/320C3x.pdf starting with section 4.3